# JPA - Could not get primary key generated in a one-to-one relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I'm trying to create JPA mappings for following database tables:
[image]

The fields ID_CODA, ID_MOVEMENT and ID_INFORMATION are generated by sequences in the database and I would like to persist the whole CODA object to the database in one transaction.

Here's what I've already done:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "CODA_TEST")
public class CodedAccountStatement implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_CODA")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_coda", sequenceName = "seq_coda", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_coda")
    private long identifier;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "statement")
    private List<MovementRecord> movements;

    public void addMovement(MovementRecord movementRecord) {
        if(this.movements == null) {
            this.movements = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        movementRecord.setStatement(this);
        this.movements.add(movementRecord);
    }
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "CODA_ARTICLE_MOUVEMENT_TEST")
@IdClass(MovementRecordIdentifier.class)
public class MovementRecord implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_MOUVEMENT")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_coda_article_mouvement", sequenceName = "seq_coda_article_mouvement",allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_coda_article_mouvement")
    private long movementId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CODA", referencedColumnName = "ID_CODA")
    private CodedAccountStatement statement;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "movementRecord")
    private DomiciliationRecord domiciliationRecord;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "movementId")
    private List<InformationRecord> informationRecords;

    public void setDomiciliationRecord(DomiciliationRecord domiciliationRecord) {
        domiciliationRecord.setMovementRecord(this);
        this.domiciliationRecord = domiciliationRecord;
    }

    public void addInformationRecord(InformationRecord informationRecord) {
        if(this.informationRecords == null) {
            this.informationRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        informationRecord.setMovementId(this);
        this.informationRecords.add(informationRecord);
    }
```

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(InformationRecordIdentifier.class)
@Table(name = "CODA_ARTICLE_INFORMATION_TEST")
public class InformationRecord implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "ID_MOUVEMENT", referencedColumnName = "ID_MOUVEMENT"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CODA", referencedColumnName = "ID_CODA")
    })
    private MovementRecord movementId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_INFORMATION")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_coda_article_information", sequenceName = "seq_coda_article_information", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_coda_article_information")
    private long informationId;
```

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(MovementRecordIdentifier.class)
@Table(name = "CODA_ARTICLE_MOUVEMENT_DOM_TEST")
public class DomiciliationRecord implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_MOUVEMENT")
    private long movementId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_CODA")
    private long statement;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "ID_MOUVEMENT"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CODA")
    })
    private MovementRecord movementRecord;
```

And here's how I persist this object using `Spring Data Jpa` interface:

```java
    private final CodedAccountStatementRepository repository;

    @Transactional
    public void save() {
        CodedAccountStatement statement = new CodedAccountStatement();

        MovementRecord movementRecord = new MovementRecord();
        movementRecord.setDomiciliationRecord(new DomiciliationRecord());
        movementRecord.addInformationRecord(new InformationRecord());

        statement.addMovement(movementRecord);

        LOGGER.info("Coda to save = {}", statement);
        repository.save(statement);
    }
```

And as you can see from logs:

```
insert into CODA_TEST (ID_CODA) values (?)
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [140]
insert into CODA_ARTICLE_MOUVEMENT_TEST (ID_MOUVEMENT, ID_CODA) values (?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [3400]
binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [140]
insert into CODA_ARTICLE_INFORMATION_TEST (ID_INFORMATION, ID_MOUVEMENT, ID_CODA) values (?, ?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [127]
binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [3400]
binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [140]
insert into CODA_ARTICLE_MOUVEMENT_DOM_TEST (ID_MOUVEMENT, ID_CODA) values (?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [0]
binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [0]
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (EGCA1.FK_CODA_ARTICLE_MOUVEMENT_DOM_CODA_TEST) violated - parent key not found
```

The identifiers have been correctly generated for each entity but Hibernate is not giving the right values for the `DomiciliationRecord` primary key (we have 0, 0)...

Comment: The problem (as you have seen) is that there's nothing that tells hibernate about how to populate the id of `DomiciliationRecord`. I haven't worked with Hibernate for a few years, but (if I recall correctly) in this type of scenarios you have to use `@EmbeddedId` rather than `@IdClass` with `@Id`, as that allows the id to be autopopulated. A word of caution, it's sometimes considered a good practice to use simple numerical id or GUID if you know that your application will use an ORM, as mapping complex PK and FKs is not trivial and can end up polluting the code. &add any other id as unique idx

Comment: @Augusto thank you. I've read questions about `@EmbeddedId` but it seems that you can't use it with `@GeneratedValue` as I want. I've reduced the complexity of my problem see my answer below.

Comment: Glad it helped! If you need some references for this approach (as some people don't like), I have the strong feeling this is described in the book *Implementing Domain-Driven Design* and has some extra explanation of the benefits.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Augusto comment I've changed my database tables this way:
[image]

This reduces complexity of my problem and the mapping is now trivial.

Comment: It's always nice when you are free to change a database to make code easier to maintain. Don't expect to be able to do that every time, it's very worth it to learn how to do complex JPA mapping scenarios like setting up a composite key.